# are arrays equal method in java

Tags: java, arrays

im a newbie, i need to write a method that check if 2 arrays are equal in the values and order, if they are print true, else false
this is what i wrote and the result always true, if i try printing the values that the function recieve in the arrays for some reason **they are all 0.**

```
public static boolean areArraysEqual(int[] firstArr, int[] secArr) {
    firstArr = new int[N];
    secArr = new int[N];
    System.out.println(firstArr.length);
    if(firstArr.length != secArr.length){
        return false;
    }
    if(firstArr == null || secArr == null){
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < firstArr.length; i++) {
        if(firstArr[i] != secArr[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You're overwriting the arrays as soon as you enter the function

Comment: `firstArr = new int[N];` and `secArr = new int[N];` will always be equal to one another.

Comment: [`Arrays.equals(int[], int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(int[],%20int[])) would probably help.

Answer (score 2):

When you try to re-allocate the arguments firstArr and secArr, the original array contents get lost.
No need to re-allocte firstArr and secArr, since in java, array objects are passed by value, they can be used as-is for its contents.
The following code snippet is good enough:

```
public static boolean areArraysEqual(int[] firstArr, int[] secArr) {
    if(firstArr == null || secArr == null || firstArr.length != secArr.length){
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < firstArr.length; i++) {
        if(firstArr[i] != secArr[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You could explain what the problem was. @Dr.DebasishJana

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you are re-declaring the array. Remove `firstArr = new int[N];` and `secArr = new int[N];` from your code. Then it should work fine.

```
public static boolean areArraysEqual(int[] firstArr, int[] secArr) {
    System.out.println(firstArr.length);
    if(firstArr.length != secArr.length){
        return false;
    }
    if(firstArr == null || secArr == null){
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < firstArr.length; i++) {
        if(firstArr[i] != secArr[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Side note:   If this is not for academic/competitive purpose use [`Array.equals(firstArr, secArr)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two new arrays, which are initialized to all zeros with

```
firstArr = new int[N];
secArr = new int[N];
```

When you call `areArraysEqual(int[] firstArr, int[] secArr)` you are supplying two arrays already, there is no reason to create new ones.

Removing those two lines should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing the already submitted answers don't cover, but you've got far too much code written for this. Try this:

```
public boolean compareArrays(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    if (Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Arrays.equals covers order and size, no need to check for nulls either, that should be handled by the caller, after all, null does equal null and there for the arrays are equal.